# C#: How do you pass an object in a function parameter?

Tags: c#

C#: How do you pass an object in a function parameter?

```
public void MyFunction(TextBox txtField)
{
  txtField.Text = "Hi.";
}
```

Would the above be valid? Or?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So long as you're not in a different thread, yes the code sample is valid. A textbox (or other windows forms items) are still objects that can be passed to and manipulated by methods.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it and your swift response.

Answer (score 8):

Yup, that will work. You're not actually passing an object - you're passing in a *reference* to the object.

See ["Parameter passing in C#"](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for details when it comes to pass-by-ref vs pass-by-value.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my understanding on the use of the terms. Your reply and "information references" are also highly appreciated.

Comment: link to "Parameter passing in C#" no longer valid.

Comment: @CarolinaJay65: Fixed now. For some reason pobox.com had lost my URL forwarding...

Answer (score 4):

For any reference-type, that is fine - you have passed the *reference* to the object, but there is only one object, so changes are visible to the caller.

The main time that *won't* work is for "structs" (value-types) - but they really shouldn't be mutable anyway (i.e. they shouldn't really have editable properties).

If you *needed* to do this with a struct, you could add "ref" - i.e.

```
public void MyFunction(ref MyMutableStruct whatever)
{
  whatever.Value = "Hi."; // but avoid mutable structs in the first place!
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't structs be mutable? Aren't they just a lighter-weight version of classes?

Comment: @DOK: No, they're completely different. They behave very differently, and if you make structs mutable you *will* run into problems. Just say no.

Comment: Structs are treated as value types, not object references. Passing a struct is like passing an int, any change you make to the integer won't leave the method.